# plusMinus function from Hacker Rank

Tags: c#

I'm trying to solve a task from HackerRank, but I'm not able to solve it. Any help is appreciated!

```
public static void plusMinus(List<int> arr)
{
    float noOfPositive = 0;
    float noOfNegative = 0;
    float noOfZero = 0;
    
    float length = arr.Count;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++){
        if(i > 0){
            noOfPositive += 1;
        }else if(i == 0){
            noOfZero += 1;
        }else{
            noOfNegative += 1;
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{noOfPositive/length}\n{noOfNegative/length}\n{noOfZero/length}");
```

input:

```
6

-4 3 -9 0 4 1
```

My Result:

```
0.8333333

0

0.1666667
```

Expected:
0.500000

```
0.333333

0.166667
```

Comment: But what about telling us the problem's condition? Just sayin' ;)

Comment: You're checking the value of the index, not the data in the array at that index. Therefore the only value that won't be positive is 0 (the first index you reach in the loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the value of `i` not `arr[i]`.
So your code should be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++){
    if(arr[i] > 0){
        noOfPositive += 1;
    }else if(arr[i] == 0){
        noOfZero += 1;
    }else{
        noOfNegative += 1;
    }
}
```

And your expected values are wrong, you are putting in 7 items and expecting half of them to be positive so 3.5 items are positive?

Comment: I believe OP is instructing the code that three will be 6 items, and then supplying those 6 items. That code isn't shown though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: You could be right, i was assuming the newline was a typo.